# Android pdf viewer - ActivityNotFoundException : No Activity found to handle Intent

Tags: android, pdf, activitynotfoundexception

I want to open pdf file from url, so I used this code:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
browserIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(string), "application/pdf");
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

It's worked when the protocol is http, but not working if the protocol is `https`, I got error `ActivityNotFoundException`, any idea to fix this?

Comment: show your string value also

Comment: Add try-catch block and DEBUG

Comment: ya it can't works because you should have to add the SSL certificate for HTTPS secure connection. that's why it will not work on HTTPS.

Comment: Have a look on this answer, He had the same problem: [Android - No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW - Trying to open a PDF File](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25949838/4575580)

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley the string is => "https://repository.usd.ac.id/6475/2/119114066_full.pdf"

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I got error ActivityNotFoundException

Comment: @ShubhamSejpal I have add the SSL certificate for HTTPS, but its not working too, may you share your code please?

Comment: @AshishGupta I want to open pdf file from url, not from sdcard

Comment: @Enda Does you have a SSL Certificate of that particular server with you?

Answer (score 0):

> It's worked when the protocol is http, but not working if the protocol is https

Apparently, your device does not have a PDF viewer that supports downloading directly from `https` URLs.

> any idea to fix this?

Download the PDF yourself (e.g., using OkHttp3 or `HttpUrlConnection`). Then, try opening a PDF viewer on the downloaded PDF (e.g., using `FileProvider` to serve it locally via a `content` `Uri`).